# Where is Rails.env set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

On my server inside of `/etc/nginx/sites-available/appname` I have `passenger_enabled on;` and `rails_env production;` set. For some reason when I run rails r "puts Rails.env" it spits out development. I've searched my app for the setting of the rails env but I don't see it anywhere. I'm hoping someone can guide me in the direction of why the setting inside of the nginx appname config is being overridden with development.

Versions:

nginx/1.14.0

Rails 4.2.6

EDIT:
Passenger server config:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate     /path/to/appname/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/appname/privkey.pem;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers "lkajsdflkjsalfkdjlsaf";
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  client_max_body_size 32000M;
  server_name    domain.com;
  root /home/ubuntu/www/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When passenger loads your app, it overrides your local environment settings with what you set via rails_env. See https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_app_env which states

> This option sets, for the current application, the value of the
>   following environment variables:
>
> ```
> RAILS_ENV
> RACK_ENV
> WSGI_ENV
> NODE_ENV
> PASSENGER_APP_ENV
> ```

When. you run 'rails r' on the command line, that is looking for the RAILS_ENV setting as mentioned in the other answers here, which is completely separate from the nginx/passenger settings. Try adding something like

```
<%= Rails.env %>
```

in a view, and looking at your application in production.  You should see that it is indeed production, while you are free to use any environment you want when you use the CLI rails command, which defaults to development.

Comment: That makes sense...somewhat. I was thinking the same thing but in the database.yml file I have a development and production config. When starting my app via `service nginx start` I get an error from the rails app saying that the development database doesn't exist. This tells me, unless i'm missing something, that nginx/passenger is trying to run the app in the development environment. The development database doesn't exist on my staging server as the config just uses the default config options.

Comment: Hrm. My first thought is that perhaps you have multiple Rails applications and it's complaining about a different one. My second thought is to try to force RAILS_ENV via https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_env_var and add to your passenger config:  passenger_env_var RAILS_ENV production;   If neither of those help, I suggest posting your passenger config so we can take a look to see if something seems off, there.

Comment: added the server config.

Answer (score 0):

RAILS_ENV is set to `development` by default.

When you need to override it, use the environment variable `RAILS_ENV`. Try this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails r "puts Rails.env"
```

doc: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-environment-settings

Comment: I thought by setting the rails_env flag in the nginx config would change the default.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify rails environment using RAILS_ENV=production after the command u want to run.

if you want to start rails console for production environment then use

```
rails console RAILS_ENV=production
rails server RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: I want to run the app in the production environment. I'm using nginx and passenger so I'm not starting the server via `rails server RAILS_ENV=production`